# Define multi run config with same package.json file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, phpstorm, nodemon

I have an Electron application that run into a node.js server. And I also want to work with "nodemon" for live execution node server.

This 2 previous sentences getting up 3 different execution possible into start key in package.json file :

- electron .
- node server.js
- nodemon server.js

I would like quickly switch between those execution command. I can create a Run/Config template with PhpStorm but all of those save command run with the same package.json file that wrote the start command.

How can I use the same package.json for working with 3 execution environments?

Comment: don't understand what you are talking about. you can create 3 separate scripts in your package.json, 1 for each of your environments, and use the preferred one

Comment: I don't want use 1 dev, 1 test and 1 prod environnement BUT many dev, many test and many prod execution.